# GCM Push Notifications sent multiple times or to wrong users

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have an app in production that has GCM notifications. There are two levels of users: a regular user and a privileged user.

Now, every time a user logs in, I store the registration ID in my database. When the user logs out, I delete the registration ID. This works fine.

But, when a user doesn't log out, deletes/reinstalls the app and logs in as a different type of user (i.e regular before and privileged now or vice versa), he receives notifications that he shouldn't be receiving.

Or if he logs in as a new user (either regular or privileged), he receives the same notification multiple times. I'm guessing this is because the older registration ID is still in the database, and there is a new one as well.

How do I avoid this? Android docs show that calling the [unregister](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html) method isn't suggested.

Comment: registration Id is id of the device, not the user. So 10 users on same phone would have same regId

Comment: @MarkoNiciforovic Exactly. So if there are multiple users on the same phone (some privileged and some not) how do I make sure that notifications are delivered to the right people even though reg id is the same??

Comment: I don't think it is possible if user doesn't log out. Not really sure, best to be to wait for someone that has more knowledge than me about GCM, but as far as I know its not possible without user logging out because you must call your server and delete the old registration id from your db. Obviously you can "force a logout" - you can implicitly logout the previous user when a new user logs in. When the new user logs in, you set the reg ID for the new user and clear it for any other user which was previously associated with this ID.

Answer (score 0):

I store the registration ID in my database ==> This should be saved on server

When a user doesn't log out ==> You need to maintain a session object for this

deletes/reinstalls the app & logs in as a different type of user ==> Add check on server side to disallow same values to be inserted twice. Just kake that column UNIQUE.

if he logs in as a new user (either regular or privileged), he receives the same notification multiple times. ==> You need to identify the user with a uniqueID.

**Proposed Solution**

Table: LoggedInUsers on Server: [UserID(PK), GCM_ID, UserType]

```
    Login(UserID,GCM_ID,UserType)
    if(UserID does not exist in your onLine DataBse)
    {
    Insert(UserID,GCM_ID,UserType);
    }

  if(UserID exist in your onLine DataBse)
  {
  Update(UserID,GCM_ID,UserType)
  }

LogOut(UserID)
{
deleteUser(UserID); 
}
```

Hope this helps.Cheers!